# swfobject and installing flash

Tags: flash, swfobject

I've embedded the following into the page, but if flash isn't installed nothing happens I thought that it would prompt you to install?

Any ideas?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var flashvars = {
            modelURL: '/flash/testvideo.swf' ,
            modelID: "1",
            bgColor: "0xFFFFFF",
            initialXRot: "25",
            initialZRot: "0",
            initialAutoRotate: "true",
            initialAutoRotateSpeed: "4",
            enableMouseClick: "false",
            debug: "false"
        };
        var params = {
            menu: "false",
            scale: "noScale",
            allowFullscreen: "true",
            allowScriptAccess: "always",
            bgcolor: "",
            wmode: "direct" // can cause issues with FP settings & webcam
        };
        var attributes = {
            id: "rdsModel"
        };
        swfobject.embedSWF(
        "/scripts/3dviewer/ModelViewer.swf",
        "altContent", "280", "280", "11.1.0",
        "scripts/3dviewer/expressInstall.swf",
        flashvars, params, attributes);
    });
```

I've got the following div which is where the content is being displayed.

```
 <div id="altContent"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your div add `<div id="altContent">Instructions to install flash</div>`

Also, I would check if there are any JavaScript errors.

**Edit**

One way to hide the message until needed is to first leave your altContent div blank:

`<div id="altContent"></div>`

then at the end of your document ready function add:

```
if (!swfobject.hasFlashPlayerVersion("9")) {
  $('#altContent').html('Message to get some Flash!');
}
```

If the Flash version is lower than 9 or if Flash is not installed it should show your "no flash message".

Comment: I've tried that, and it does indeed work but when you have flashed installed you see that content for a bit until the flash kicks in, which isn't going to be acceptable to my client.